# how to re-try request for 401 along with TransientHttpError ( 5XX and 408)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

Below code re-try 2 times when we have error from HttpRequestException, 5XX and 408 and it's works fine.

Here I want to re-try for even `401` error? how we can achieve this with Polly?

```
 services.AddHttpClient(Options.DefaultName)
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler { })
            .AddPolicyHandler(HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))));
```

Comment: What is your reason for `.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler { })`? Isn't that the default already without manually specifying it?

Comment: Why do you want retry the same request if you receive `Unauthorized`? Issuing the same request normally does not give you new credentials. Or did I miss something?

Comment: We will perform again ReAuthorize in case 401.

Comment: @user584018 Exactly, whenever you encounter a 401 then you want to perform a *specific action* rather than issuing the same request.  That's why I don't get it why do you want to include 401 into your generic retry logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `.OrResult(r => r.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)` to your code:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient(Options.DefaultName)
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler { })
        .AddPolicyHandler(HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
        .OrResult(r => r.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))));
```

I would suggest rewriting your code like this to make it easier to read:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient(Options.DefaultName)
        .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(builder => 
            builder
                .OrResult(r => r.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))))
        );
```

Comment: will it re-try only for 401. What if 500 comes?

Comment: `HandleTransientHttpError`, which you already have, handles 5xx and 408.

Comment: what if I wanto to do something, like an OAuth authentication, before retry the request?

Comment: @AngeloBernardi I would normally create a `DelegatingHandler` for that. You can then register it using `.AddHttpMessageHandler<MyDelegatingHandlerType>()`